# Как удалить данные из нескольких таблиц MySQL?

Tags: mysql

По идее, запрос должен удалить записи из таблицы `catalog` и `product_to_catalog`, где `catalog.id` и `product_to_catalog.catalog_id` одинаковы и найти записи в таблице `product` с `product.id = product_to_catalog.product_id` и тоже их удалить.
В чем я допустил ошибку?

```sql
DELETE c.*,pc.*,p.* FROM `catalog` c 
LEFT JOIN `product_to_catalog` pc
ON c.id = pc.catalog_id 
LEFT JOIN `product` p 
ON p.id = pc.product_id
WHERE c.id = 2
```

Comment: Вам действительно помогло убирание `.*` после синонимов таблиц? Просто судя по синтаксису команды `delete` и тестовым запросам - они абсолютно равнозначны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо после `DELETE` перечислить название тех таблиц из которых удаляются данные, не надо писать `table_name.*`, это всё-таки не запрос выборки данных.

```
DELETE c, pc, p FROM `catalog` c 
LEFT JOIN `product_to_catalog` pc
ON c.id = pc.catalog_id 
LEFT JOIN `product` p 
ON p.id = pc.product_id
WHERE c.id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать модельный пример, то Ваш запрос все прекрасно удаляет. 
[Sql Fiddle пример.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b63db/1)

Учитывая то, что в запросе используются `LEFT JOIN` могут быть удалены записи только из таблицы `catalog` если в других таблицах не будет найдено соответствующих записей.

---

Если [посмотреть](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) на синтаксис команды `delete`:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

То нет никакой разница между `c.*,pc.*,p.*` и `c, pc, p`.

Answer (score 0):

Похожий вопрос (с решением):

[Медленно работает либо не работает удаление из нескольких таблиц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507899/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86/508328#508328)

думаю ответ оттуда отвечает и на этот.
ну, и коментарии (к ответу) гляньте.