# Медленно работает либо не работает удаление из нескольких таблиц

Tags: mysql

```
delete c_price_list,c_lees,c_price,c_propel,c_impel FROM c_price_list 
LEFT JOIN c_impel  ON c_impel.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_lees ON c_lees.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_price ON c_price.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_propel  ON c_propel.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
WHERE c_price_list.`date`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

2способ

```
delete from c_impel,c_lees,c_price,c_propel,c_price_list
using c_impel,c_lees,c_price,c_price_list,c_propel
where
c_impel.id_price_list=c_price_list.id and
c_lees.id_price_list=c_price_list.id and
c_price.id_price_list=c_price_list.id and
c_propel.id_price_list=c_price_list.id and
c_price_list.`date`<DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Я хочу удалить из таблиц все данные 2дней назад. Индексы c_price_list.id(Primary key),id_price_list(key). Жду час-два,- ничего не удаляется- число строк в таблицах остается до-сих пор таким же.

Comment: 1. Сколько записей удаляется за раз, может их много и следует выполнить несколько ограниченных LIMIT запросов? 2. Если превратить DELETE-запрос в SELECT и выполнить EXPLAIN, в нем все нормально? Все внешние ключи проиндексированы?

Comment: вернее жду час, ничего не удаляется.-(

Comment: Насколько велики таблицы?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/aloeq0

Comment: Очень компактные таблицы, попробуйте выполнить EXPLAIN для аналогичного SELECT-запроса, что он дает?

Comment: выполняется до-сих пор-(
`explain select * FROM c_price_list 
LEFT JOIN c_impel  ON c_impel.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_lees ON c_lees.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_price ON c_price.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_propel  ON c_propel.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
WHERE c_price_list.`date`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)`

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что таблицы блокированы предыдущим DELETE-запросом. Грохните его - успеете еще выполнить. Для завершения запроса можно использовать команду KILL, PID запроса можно посмотреть через SHOW PROCESSLIST. А потом выполните EXPLAIN SELECT.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/aloky4, когда грохнула- я увидела- что удалилось

Comment: С индексацией все идеально, может индексов слишком много...

Comment: Указанные в вопросе индексы участвуют в запросе. Как могут индексы, не участвующие в запросе, влиять на производительность? Правда , у моей таблицы c_price_list id был просто key, я го потом сделала primary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы удалял не из 5-ти таблиц сразу одним запросом (даже не уверен, что так можно), а выполнял бы 5 соответствующих запросов удаления:

```
delete c_propel FROM c_price_list 
LEFT JOIN c_impel  ON c_impel.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_lees ON c_lees.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_price ON c_price.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_propel  ON c_propel.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
WHERE c_price_list.`date`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

---

```
delete c_price FROM c_price_list 
LEFT JOIN c_impel  ON c_impel.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_lees ON c_lees.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_price ON c_price.id_price_list=c_price_list .id    
WHERE c_price_list.`date`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

---

```
delete c_lees FROM c_price_list 
LEFT JOIN c_impel  ON c_impel.id_price_list=c_price_list .id
LEFT JOIN c_lees ON c_lees.id_price_list=c_price_list .id    
WHERE c_price_list.`date`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

---

```
delete c_impel FROM c_price_list 
LEFT JOIN c_impel  ON c_impel.id_price_list=c_price_list .id    
WHERE c_price_list.`date`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

---

```
delete c_price_list 
WHERE c_price_list.`date`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Comment: почему вы думаете, что нельзя удалять из 5 таблиц одним запросом. . Наверное, так и сделаю.

Comment: @RRR , просто интуитивно, таблицы связаны, непонятный внутренний порядок удаления, где-то возможно попасть на уже отсутствующую или заблокированную связанную запись

Comment: @RRR, только во время выполнения этих 5-ти удалений нужно быть уверенным что из-вне эти строки никто не изменяет, добавляет.
думаю достаточно обернуть все эти запросы одной транзакцией

Comment: у меня в эти таблички непрерывно добавляются записи, нельзя ли ранние записи- двух дней назад (они никогда не обновляются, просто добавляются) удалять?

Comment: в вашем запросе связи между таблицами имеют вид стандартных связей 'один ко многим', т.е. каждая запись подчиненных таблиц принадлежат только одной записи в таблице более верхнего уровня.   а условие выборки записей в главной таблице включают в себя условие - старше 2х дней. Соответственно, если эти записи (старше 2 дней) - не изменяются и уже не добавляются, то и множество строк, подлежащих удалению меняться не будет (если дата не изменится во время этого удаления). Видимо в этом случае можно безопасно удалять.

Comment: это если у вас в поле c_price_list.`date` лежит именно дата, если же там есть и время, то этот список (на удаление) будет меняться.
В этом случае нужно во временную таблицу выбрать id строк из c_price_list. И во всех запросах удаления  добавить inner join (первым после from) с этой временной таблицей по id и в каждом последующем условии join заменить c_price_list .id на id из этой временной таблицы

Comment: только сейчас заметил что подчиненные таблицы не связаны между собой, а только с главной. В этом случае в каждом из 5 запросов удаления можно исключить инструкции join с другими подчиненными таблицами, которые не удаляются данным запросом.

Comment: ну и вдогонку ))
В случае использования временной таблицы нужно УБРАТЬ ИНСТРУКЦИЮ WHERE из запросов удаления (это условие уже учтено в результатах выборки id основных записей во временную таблицу )

Comment: Спасибо, а если у меня вместо `NOW()` будет стоять определенная дата, тогда смысл во временной таблице я не вижу. Спасибо за мысли.